# workbox: precacheController cleanup error

Tags: workbox

I am setting a precache controller following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#advanced_usage). It seems to work fine, only for the cleanup part.

```
// Precache items
const precacheManifest = 
[
    {url: offlinePage, revision: '1.0.2'},
    {url: HomePage, revision: '1.0.2'},
    {url: './image/placeholder.png', revision: '1'},    
    {url: './manifest.json', revision: '1.0.1'},        
];

const precacheController = new workbox.precaching.PrecacheController(precacheName);
precacheController.addToCacheList(precacheManifest);
```

**Install event** works fine and inserts into cache on install.

```
/**
 * Install [Event]
 */
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    console.log('install event.');
    event.waitUntil(precacheController.install());
});
```

The issue is with **activate event** it returns an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: precacheController.cleanup is not a function.

```
/**
 * Activate [Event]
 */
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    console.log('activate event.');
    event.waitUntil(precacheController.cleanup());
});
```

What is wrong with my implementation?
I am using Workbox 3.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out **precacheController.cleanup()** is the wrong method to call.

The correct one form the last [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.precaching.PrecacheController):

```
/**
 * Activate [Event]
 */
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    console.log('activate event.');
    event.waitUntil(precacheController.activate());
});
```